# how to Pdf rendering in android application

Tags: java, android, pdf, open-source, rendering

I've hard time trying to do pdf rendering (viewing pdf content, copying/pasting text, copying image etc.) but i didn't get any open source api for this.

Can anybody share his experiences in this concern.

Any kind of help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an intent to allow the pdf to be viewed in some external application. An example can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883355/how-to-render-pdf-in-android/).