# Render PDF in webview in android

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [android webview pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655972/android-webview-pdf)

I am trying to  open PDF in my own activity which contains large images.Using MuPDF and other Library goes slow down my app performance so I dont want to use that.

Is that possible to open PDF in own activity using webview from SD card file in android ??

Any help would be appreciated ...Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

You may find [Android PDF problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4278587/432903) same as yours (of date Nov 2010), suggesting you to open stored pdf with Intent Call.

```
   File file = new File("/sdcard/your_file.pdf");
   Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
   intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
   intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
   startActivity(intent);
```

Also check [How do I determine if Android can handle PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2790374/432903)

Comment: I dont want to use third party tool to open PDF ,I want embeded PDF viewer in my application.
Is this possible in android,If yes please suggest,How??