# How to pass byte[] to WebView?

Tags: java, android, pdf, webview

I have PDF as an byte array.How to pass `byte[]` to WebView to display on the screen?
I tried to do it:

```
byte[] pdfByteArray = getPDFFromServer();
if (pdfByteArray != null && pdfByteArray.length != 0) {
    String base64 = Base64.encodeToString(pdfByteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
    webView.loadData(base64, "text/html","UTF-8");
}
```

but it does't work.
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You are passing the byte array correctly but there's a couple of other problems: 1. WebViews don't display PDF's. 2. text/html is not a pdf. 3 text/html is not base64 encoded. This link shows a way to display a PDF (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4278422/display-pdf-in-webview)

Comment: Didn't work. I receive pdf as an byte array from server.

Comment: Then I want to convert byte array to pdf and pass it into webView. But i don't know how to do it.