# Mobile App menu link opening in browser

Tags: android, pdf, webview, web

I have made an android app by using the android webview. This app is actually a mobile site which contains the different courses.

**In the website:**
When I open the course page there is a course pdf link which when clicked opens in a new tab.

**In the android app**
When the site is opened in the mobile app, the course link (In menu) itself is getting opened in a browser.

My requirement is that the pdf link in the course page should open in a new tab.

Below is the code which I have tried.

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.education.xxxxxxx;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "";
    private WebView myWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
//        myWebView.loadUrl("http://xxxxxxx.com/");
//        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        String myPdfUrl = "http://xxxxxxx.com/";
        if(myPdfUrl.endsWith(".pdf")){
         String googledocs="https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=";
         String pdf_url=googledocs+myPdfUrl;
            myWebView.loadUrl(pdf_url);
        }
        else{
            myWebView.loadUrl(myPdfUrl);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(myWebView.canGoBack()){
            myWebView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        // getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement


        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: set webviewClient for webview, there should be a method in it shouldOverrideUrlLoading(),

Comment: I tried this..but now the pdf is not getting opened.

Comment: I don't know if webview has support for tabbed content. Default is: all it's opened at the only one existing tab, the main one. What you may do is open the pdf inside a new activity containing another webview.

Comment: @adi have a look at my answer

Comment: @adi , confirmed, webview cannot afford tabs. Please, would you mind to check my answer as the correct one? I will plus one you for it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebView does not support tabs. All is opened at the only one existing tab, the main one. What you may do is open the pdf inside a new activity containing another WebView.

Answer (score 0):

The pdf wont open directly you may use google doc viewer

```
 WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
String pdf = "http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf";
webview.loadUrl("http://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=" + pdf);
```

have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5296125/6478047)

Comment: From the OP: "page should open in a new tab"... . Yet: OP will always be notified by your answer, no need to alert him by a comment, excuse me.

Comment: @Redman I tried this but it is not opening the page itself now.