# WebView Not Loading inside Custom Dialog Layout

Tags: android, webview, android-alertdialog

I am trying to load a pdf document from web to **url** (which I accessed in browser and its working well), when I load the **url** in WebView inside Custom `AlertDialog` my WebView diaplays nothing.

**alert_dialog_webview.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingStart="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingEnd="10dp"
    >
    <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/web_view"
        ></WebView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**code:**

```
   private void showDoc(String fileName) {

        final View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog_webview, null);

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
        builder.setCancelable(false);

        final WebView webview  = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.web_view);
        String url = BASE_URL+fileName;
        //webview.loadUrl(url);
        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }

            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
                webview.loadUrl(request.getUrl().toString());
                return true;
            }
        });




        String negativeText = getString(R.string.cancel);
        builder.setNegativeButton(negativeText,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                       dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

        final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.setView(view);
 dialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
            @Override
            public void onShow(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
                dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE).setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(),R.color.colorAccentDark));

            }
        });
        // display dialog
        dialog.show();
    }
```

Comment: Why are you performing `dialog.setView(view);` twice?

Comment: you might wanna remove comment from `webview.loadUrl(url);`

Comment: @V-rundPuro-hit Why should I do so If I am setting `webViewClient `

Comment: how would your webview come to know which url to load? its ok if you are setting `webViewClient`, but you are not passing url for loading to it

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue with a `WebView` inside a `AlertDialog`, but I notice that `WebView` is loading the url but its height is very small, so it is difficult to know if is loaded de page or not.

The trick I found was that you need to add a `weight` property to WebView and use `match_parent` in the `height`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview_terms"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" <!-- use match_parent -->
        android:layout_weight="1" <!-- add this line -->
        tools:ignore="InefficientWeight" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_accept_terms"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/background_button_selector"
        android:text="@string/accept_button"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Android `Webview` do not support `PDF`, although chrome app support it.

But, if you want to open `PDF` in your app you can use [MuPDF Library](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8587527/3488710).

If you still want to open PDF in `Webview` you can use google drive's url to open the pdf file.

But, its just like a webpage opening the pdf with Google toolbar above on it.
Checkout this answer for implementing this:- 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42975739/3488710

Comment: You can load PDF in `WebView` there is workaround for that

Comment: using google drive's pre url, you can but its like a web page opening pdf.

Comment: Yah. but still you can load pdf in it. so it is wrong to say that Webview do not support PDF

Comment: pre appending the drive url worked  but still unable to understand why webview donot support direct loading of documents

Comment: Webview don't support PDF direcltly unlike the IOS Webview which supports it directly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :)

```
private void showDoc(String fileName) {

            final View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog_webview, null);

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
            builder.setCancelable(false);

            final WebView webview  = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.web_view);
            String url = "https://docs.google.com/viewer?url="+BASE_URL+fileName;
            webview.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
            webview.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
            webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
            webview.loadUrl(url);

            String negativeText = getString(R.string.cancel);
            builder.setNegativeButton(negativeText,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                           dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });

            final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.setView(view);
            dialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
                @Override
                public void onShow(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
                    dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE).setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(),R.color.colorAccentDark));

                }
            });
            // display dialog
            dialog.show();
        }
```