# Webview is not loading a PDF from an URL

Tags: android, webview

Webview is not loading a PDF from url.I am getting **Preview not Available**.

Please any one help on this thanks.,

```
private void loadUrl() {
            String reportStatus = caseList.get(position).getReportStatus();
            mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                    view.loadUrl(url);
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, final String url) {

                }
            });

            if (!reportStatus.isEmpty()) {
                String reportPath = caseList.get(position).getReportPath();
                String url = "http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + reportPath;
                String doc = "<iframe src='" + url + "' width='100%' height='100%' style='border: none;'></iframe>";
                if (!reportPath.isEmpty()) {
                    mWebView.loadData(doc, "text/html", "UTF-8");
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I display a pdf document into a Webview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655972/how-can-i-display-a-pdf-document-into-a-webview)

Comment: @V-rundPuro-hit Not working

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49147768/7319704

Comment: What is it doing? a blank page or something else?

Comment: @Avi It is showing Preview not available

Comment: does url is working on chrome or browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi try the below code,

```
String url = null;
        try {
            url = URLEncoder.encode("file url", "utf-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String path = "http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + url;
        mWebView.loadUrl(path);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the google docs url to `https` from `http`

```
private void loadUrl() {
        String reportStatus = caseList.get(position).getReportStatus();
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, final String url) {

            }
        });

        if (!reportStatus.isEmpty()) {
            String reportPath = caseList.get(position).getReportPath();
            String url = "https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + reportPath;
            String doc = "<iframe src='" + url + "' width='100%' height='100%' style='border: none;'></iframe>";
            if (!reportPath.isEmpty()) {
                mWebView.loadData(doc, "text/html", "UTF-8");
            }
        }
    }
```