# Cannot resolve method 'subscribe(anonymous org.reactivestreams.Subscriber<java.io.File>)

Tags: java, android, rx-java2

I am trying to download and send pdf using Intent to PDF app to display the file as seen here as the [answer of JDenais](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655972/how-can-i-display-a-pdf-document-into-a-webview.)
This is the code to download the pdf and pass it via Intent.

```
public class PdfOpenHelper {

public static void openPdfFromUrl(final String pdfUrl, final Activity activity) {
    Observable.fromCallable(new Callable<File>() {
        @Override
        public File call() throws Exception {
            try {
                URL url = new URL(pdfUrl);
                URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
                connection.connect();

                // download the file
                InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
                File dir = new File(activity.getFilesDir(), "/shared_pdf");
                dir.mkdir();
                File file = new File(dir, "temp.pdf");
                OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file);

                byte data[] = new byte[1024];
                long total = 0;
                int count;
                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                    total += count;
                    output.write(data, 0, count);
                }

                output.flush();
                output.close();
                input.close();
                return file;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    })
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<File>() {
                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(Subscription s) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(File file) {
                    String authority = activity.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".fileprovider";
                    Uri uriToFile = FileProvider.getUriForFile(activity, authority, file);

                    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    shareIntent.setDataAndType(uriToFile, "application/pdf");
                    shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                    if (shareIntent.resolveActivity(activity.getPackageManager()) != null) {
                        activity.startActivity(shareIntent);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable t) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {

                }
            });
}
}
```

But I am getting the error

> 'Cannot resolve method `subscribe(anonymous
>   org.reactivestreams.Subscriber<java.io.File>)` on `.subscribe(new
>   Subscriber<File>()`

I am new to rx java, I don't know what is wrong with code.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `rx-java2` consumer type changed. Use `io.reactivex.Observer` to subscribe to `io.reactivex.Observable`. `org.reactivestreams.Subscriber` is used only for `io.reactivex.Flowable` subscriptions.

```
.subscribe(new Observer<File>() {
        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(Subscription s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(File file) { 

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable t) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {

        }
    });
```