# PDF not open in WebView from Url

Tags: android, pdf

I try to open the pdf in WebView from url, but it is not opening.It showing no preview available. It opening correctly on web. I also enable the JavaScriptEnabled.I try it for last one day but not able to oprn the pdf.Coud anyone please help me in it. 
[I use this pdf link to open in WebView](http://54.64.229.48/dev/sites/default/files/final_features%20for%20Oh%2527%20My%20Concierge_29_06_2018.pdf)

Comment: try opening it with google doc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I display a pdf document into a Webview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655972/how-can-i-display-a-pdf-document-into-a-webview)

Comment: show your code.. @Rishikesh Rahi

Comment: @Ankita i follwed this way    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        String filename ="http://54.64.229.48//dev//sites//default//files//final_features%20for%20Oh%2527%20My%20Concierge_29_06_2018.pdf";
        webview.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + filename);

        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                // do your stuff here
                progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });

Comment: Try to check either the URL of file is not null like (https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=null)

Comment: @ Ankita the pdf is opening in web you can also check it i am giving you the pdf link :- http://54.64.229.48//dev//sites//default//files//final_features%20for%20Oh%2527%20My%20Concierge_29_06_2018.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Use google docs to open PDF in webview like below

```
https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=http://54.64.229.48/dev/sites/default/files/final_features%2520for%2520Oh%252527%2520My%2520Concierge_29_06_2018.pdf
```

hope it helps.

Comment: when i used the above url it now opening html file not pdf

Comment: @Rishikesh please copy and paste same URL as below

https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=http://54.64.229.48/dev/sites/default/files/final_features%2520for%2520Oh%252527%2520My%2520Concierge_29_06_2018.pdf

Comment: still same problem.

Comment: Its working good on my side, If you have noticed that there is a minor change in your pdf URL that I mentioned in the comment, please paste comment's URL as it is.

Comment: ..what have you do with the original url..can you please explain a bit

Comment: your pdf URL contain emply space, avoid empty space in URL.
I have replaced % to Unicode char with %25
refer this link http://www.greentea.markschwing1.com/unico.html
If this answer working for you please accept this answer.

Comment: actually url comes from backened..so how do i avoid the empty space. Please crarify me in it.

Comment: i have just joined the stack overflow and my reputation is less than 15 that's why i enable to vote you. If  i can the i definitely vote you 5 for this.

Answer (score 0):

```
String pdfUrl="http://54.64.229.48/dev/sites/default/files/final_features%20for%20Oh%2527%20My%20Concierge_29_06_2018.pdf"; 

String url = "http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + pdfUrl; 

webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 

webView.loadUrl(url);
```

Comment: still it is not working. when using above code it redirected to web page and showing no preview available.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code and let me know if it works for you **Remember it will not open pdf in WebView**

```
Intent viewPdfIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
viewPdfIntent.setData(Uri.parse("http://54.64.229.48/dev/sites/default/files/final_features%20for%20Oh%2527%20My%20Concierge_29_06_2018.pdf"));
viewPdfIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
if (viewPdfIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivity(viewPdfIntent);
}
```

**And for WebView you can use**

```
 private void setUpWebView(String documentUrl) {
        webView.setWebViewClient(new AppWebViewClients());
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(false);
        webView.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url="
                + documentUrl);

    }
```

and

```
 public class AppWebViewClients extends WebViewClient {


        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);

        }
    }
```

Don't Forget to add in manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: it is opening but i want to open in webView. How do i open it in webView?

Comment: private void setUpWebView(String documentUrl) {
        webview.setWebViewClient(new AppWebViewClients());
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(false);
        webview.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url="
                + documentUrl);

    }


    private class AppWebViewClients extends WebViewClient {


    }

Comment: String pdfUrl="http://54.64.229.48/dev/sites/default/files/final_features%20for%20Oh%2527%20My%20Concierge_29_06_2018.pdf";

Comment: My Mistake i forget to add `AppWebViewClients` check updated answer

Comment: still same issue.

Comment: but i have solved by using this link:-  https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=http://54.64.229.48/dev/sites/default/files/final_features%2520for%2520Oh%252527%2520My%2520Concierge_29_06_2018.pdf

Comment: then why you say still same issue

Comment: no actually the way you mentioned is still not working

Comment: the url contains the empty space..for that i have to customize the url. That's why it isnot working coreectly in webView