# how to read pdf file file in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm a beginner in android development , I want to make android app that can read pdf files. the pdf files that i have is with large contests (each pdf file around 60 mb) , as i searched i need to store the files in the server like website or something ( i don't know exactly is that what i need ) if i will store the files on server how can i make the users read the pdf files without downloading them into their phones? .
i found that i need to use web view but i'm not sure if this is the right way .  and if what i'm thinking is wrong way please tell me what is the right way .i hope someone will help me because i'm searching for this and i'm not finding any specific answer .thank you

Comment: Yes, you'll need to use web view if you don't want to download the file. You'll also need to set up a URL on the server which renders and hosts the pdf. If you don't want to handle that, you can use the one google docs provides but I'd advice against it in production code. Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5296125/2923505

Comment: hey @Saurabh thank you for replying . i don't have any problem with server ,but what i saw that when i will use web view i need to use google docs viewer and google docs viewer will allow the users to download the pdf file . is there any library or viewer that i can use and will allow the user for only read the pdf file only ?? thanks

Comment: I'm not aware of any. In that case, you'd have to render it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can view a pdf file in an android project in different ways. I will describe some of them here-

**1. Using Library:**
Steps are below: 
**Installation**
Add to *build.gradle*:
`implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2'`

**ProGuard**
If you are using ProGuard, add following rule to proguard config file:
`-keep class com.shockwave.**`

**Include PDFView in your layout**
`<com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView
        android:id="@+id/pdfView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>`

Further link is [here](https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer)

**2. Load pdf url into webview:**

```
webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
    progressbar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    String filename = file_url_with_name;
    webview.loadUrl(file_url + filename);

    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            // do your stuff here
            progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
```

**3. Manually show PDF file into `Imageview`**

```
// Example for creating manual PDF viewer into imageview used butterknife view binding<br/>

public class PdfRenderActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @BindView(R.id.pdf_image) ImageView imageViewPdf;
    @BindView(R.id.button_pre_doc) FloatingActionButton prePageButton;
    @BindView(R.id.button_next_doc) FloatingActionButton nextPageButton;

    private static final String FILENAME = "report.pdf";

    private int pageIndex;
    private PdfRenderer pdfRenderer;
    private PdfRenderer.Page currentPage;
    private ParcelFileDescriptor parcelFileDescriptor;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pdf_render);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        pageIndex = 0;
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        try {
            openRenderer(getApplicationContext());
            showPage(pageIndex);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        try {
            closeRenderer();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        super.onStop();
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @OnClick(R.id.button_pre_doc)
    public void onPreviousDocClick(){
        showPage(currentPage.getIndex() - 1);
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @OnClick(R.id.button_next_doc)
    public void onNextDocClick(){
        showPage(currentPage.getIndex() + 1);
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    private void openRenderer(Context context) throws IOException {
        // In this sample, we read a PDF from the assets directory.
        File file = new File(context.getCacheDir(), FILENAME);
        if (!file.exists()) {
            // Since PdfRenderer cannot handle the compressed asset file directly, we copy it into
            // the cache directory.
            InputStream asset = context.getAssets().open(FILENAME);
            FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file);
            final byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int size;
            while ((size = asset.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                output.write(buffer, 0, size);
            }
            asset.close();
            output.close();
        }
        parcelFileDescriptor = ParcelFileDescriptor.open(file, ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY);
        // This is the PdfRenderer we use to render the PDF.
        if (parcelFileDescriptor != null) {
            pdfRenderer = new PdfRenderer(parcelFileDescriptor);
        }
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    private void closeRenderer() throws IOException {
        if (null != currentPage) {
            currentPage.close();
        }
        pdfRenderer.close();
        parcelFileDescriptor.close();
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    private void showPage(int index) {
        if (pdfRenderer.getPageCount() <= index) {
            return;
        }
        // Make sure to close the current page before opening another one.
        if (null != currentPage) {
            currentPage.close();
        }
        // Use `openPage` to open a specific page in PDF.
        currentPage = pdfRenderer.openPage(index);
        // Important: the destination bitmap must be ARGB (not RGB).
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(currentPage.getWidth(), currentPage.getHeight(),
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        // Here, we render the page onto the Bitmap.
        // To render a portion of the page, use the second and third parameter. Pass nulls to get
        // the default result.
        // Pass either RENDER_MODE_FOR_DISPLAY or RENDER_MODE_FOR_PRINT for the last parameter.
        currentPage.render(bitmap, null, null, PdfRenderer.Page.RENDER_MODE_FOR_DISPLAY);
        // We are ready to show the Bitmap to user.
        imageViewPdf.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        updateUi();
    }

    /**
     * Updates the state of 2 control buttons in response to the current page index.
     */
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    private void updateUi() {
        int index = currentPage.getIndex();
        int pageCount = pdfRenderer.getPageCount();
        prePageButton.setEnabled(0 != index);
        nextPageButton.setEnabled(index + 1 < pageCount);
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public int getPageCount() {
        return pdfRenderer.getPageCount();
    }

}
```

Doc is [here](https://medium.com/@chahat.jain0/rendering-a-pdf-document-in-android-activity-fragment-using-pdfrenderer-442462cb8f9a)