# How to display PDF in android WebView?

Tags: android

I am trying to display PDF into Android WebView, I found a lot of tutorials but in all tutorials, they have URL for their PDF, in my case I'm getting PDF as file in HTTP request. Is possible to show that in WebView?

My PDF response:

```
1 0 obj
    [/PDF /Text /ImageB /ImageC /ImageI]
    endobj
    13 0 obj
    << /Length 1600 /Filter /FlateDecode >> stream
    x��X�nSG�_�w�����K���BmD q�D�K|�:q�:�Jy�>B���̜�o
```

So I need the function for displaying that take response.body as parametar

Comment: did you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655972/how-can-i-display-a-pdf-document-into-a-webview)

Comment: A WebView cannot display a .pdf file.

Comment: @MohammedAlaa this is with URL

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I display a pdf document into a Webview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655972/how-can-i-display-a-pdf-document-into-a-webview)

Comment: "Is possible to show that in WebView?" -- not directly. You can hack a version of Mozilla's PDF.js to be able to display a local PDF. It would be simpler to use a PDF rendering library. See https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/01/04/options-viewing-pdfs.html for more.

Comment: @CommonsWare is there some tutorial that can explain to me how to implement that

Comment: @Niklaus: [This book](https://commonsware.com/Android/) has a chapter on rendering PDFs. The related sample code is [here](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/FINAL/PDF).