# Cant open the pdf in webview through url in android studio

Tags: android, pdf, url, webview

I tried both of the following

```
    webviewurl = "https://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=" + webviewurl;

    webviewurl = "https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + webviewurl;
```

But not useful...my code is like this...

```
    mWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    if(webviewurl.contains(".pdf")){
    
        webviewurl = "https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url="+ webviewurl;

        mWebview.loadUrl(webviewurl);

    }else{
        mWebview.loadUrl(iattach);
    }
```

Comment: A WebView cannot display a pdf file.

Comment: And what is iattach? As it is choosed as there is no .pdf in your urls.

Comment: I suggest doing something like JDenais did: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45594806/12927190