# How to open pdf file inside my app (android studio, JAVA) from firebase storage link

Tags: java, android, firebase

I have pdf file stored on my firebase storage, and its link in firebase real-time database, how can I open it inside my android app (android studio, JAVA). **Not using INTENT** , but directly inside my app.

Comment: Use `WebView` if want a simple solution or checkout [PdfRenderer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfRenderer)

Comment: how to use  WebView

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655972/how-can-i-display-a-pdf-document-into-a-webview) might help

Comment: nope....not helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer with little research :-
no need of webview or Intent which opens another app

Library :-
implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2'

xml code :-

```
 <com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:id="@+id/pdfView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

JAVA code :-

```
{
 String pdfurl="firebase_access_token_of_pdf_file";

 pdfView = (PDFView) findViewById(R.id.pdfView);
 new RetrivePDFfromUrl().execute(pdfUrl);
}

 // create an async task class for loading pdf file from URL.
class RetrivePDFfromUrl extends AsyncTask<String, Void, InputStream> {
    @Override
    protected InputStream doInBackground(String... strings) {
        // we are using inputstream
        // for getting out PDF.
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(strings[0]);
            // below is the step where we are
            // creating our connection.
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                // response is success.
                // we are getting input stream from url
                // and storing it in our variable.
                inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // this is the method
            // to handle errors.
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return inputStream;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(InputStream inputStream) {
        // after the execution of our async
        // task we are loading our pdf in our pdf view.
        pdfView.fromStream(inputStream).load();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `android-pdfView`, see this [blog post](https://upadhyayjiteshandroid.blogspot.in/2015/02/android-pdfview.html).
It demonstrates the basic usage of the library to display pdf onto the view with vertical and horizontal swipe.

```
pdfView = (PDFView) findViewById(R.id.pdfView);
pdfView.fromFile(new File("/storage/sdcard0/Download/pdf.pdf")).defaultPage(1).enableSwipe(true).onPageChange(this).load();
```

There are also other libraries like `Android PDF Viewer`,
`VuDroid` etc.

Also Android API 19 provides feasibility now to present pdf content inside an app and thus no need of 3rd party SDKs.

you can find details [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/package-summary.html).

If you want to load the file using a URL then you can use a `webview`.

```
WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
String pdf = "http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf";
webview.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + pdf);
```

Comment: I want to open file from firebase storage link .....not from asset  .....can you share any link which teaches the same ...

Comment: It works fine with every other url except firebase storage access token, its shows **no preview available**, i want to open file from firebase storage, can you test this code with firebase storage and let me know, probably I am doing something wrong